# Incomplete stairway in C

Tags: c, function

So what I need to have as a finished product is a program that:

- Asks for an int and only continues if the given is between one and eight. (Finished)
- When given the number "8" a stairway that has eight hashtags in it's bottom row must appear. (Finished)
- The stairway must be right-aligned, so there must be spaces printed to make the top right hashtag align with the bottom right hashtag. (Incomplete)
- When the stairway is given the number "1" it must simply print a single hastag. (Incomplete)

My code is as follows:

```
int main (void)
{
    int height = 0;
    int change;
    int row;
    int space;
    
    do{
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    } while(height < 1  || height > 8);

    for (change = 0; change < height; change++ )
    {
        for (space = 7; space > change; space--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (row = -1; row < change; row++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

PLease can someone tell my which functions I need to implement so I can complete the final two criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the starting value of `space` so it depends on the `height`, so you don't print more spaces than needed.

```
        for (space = height-1; space > change; space--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
```